# Google Pay Implementaion On The Web

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, google-pay

I want to add the google pay buy now button on my website, I used the below documentation for reference.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/pay-web-checkout/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0
and everything works fine and here is the code that I created.

```
<div id="buy-now"></div>

<script async
  src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
  onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
</script>


<script>
let googlePayClient;

const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
    type: 'CARD',
    parameters: {
        allowedCardNetworks: ['VISA','MASTERCARD'],
        allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY','CRYPTOGRAM_3DS']
    }
};

const googlePayBaseConfiguration = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
};

function onGooglePayLoaded() {

    googlePayClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
        environment: 'TEST'
    });

    // check compatability
    googlePayClient.isReadyToPay(googlePayBaseConfiguration)
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.result) {
            createAndAddButton();
        } else {
            alert("Unable to pay using Google Pay");
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error("Error determining readiness to use Google Pay: ", err);
    });
}

function createAndAddButton() {

    const googlePayButton = googlePayClient.createButton({

        // currently defaults to black if default or omitted
        buttonColor: 'default',

        // defaults to long if omitted
        buttonType: 'long',

        onClick: onGooglePaymentsButtonClicked
    });

    document.getElementById('buy-now').appendChild(googlePayButton);
}

function onGooglePaymentsButtonClicked() {
    // TODO: Perform transaction
    const tokenizationSpecification = {
        type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
        parameters: {
            gateway: 'example',
            gatewayMerchantId: 'gatewayMerchantId'
        }
    };

    const cardPaymentMethod = {
        type: 'CARD',
        tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification,
        parameters: {
            allowedCardNetworks: ['VISA','MASTERCARD'],
            allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY','CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
            billingAddressRequired: true,
            billingAddressParameters: {
            format: 'FULL',
            phoneNumberRequired: true
            }
        }
    };

    const transactionInfo = {
        totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
        totalPrice: '123.45',
        currencyCode: 'USD'
    };

    const merchantInfo = {
        merchantId: 'BCR2DN6TRPZNDYLL', Only in PRODUCTION
        merchantName: 'Example Merchant Name'
    };

    const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, googlePayBaseConfiguration, {
        allowedPaymentMethods: [cardPaymentMethod],
        transactionInfo: transactionInfo,
        merchantInfo: merchantInfo   
    });

    googlePayClient
    .loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
    .then(function(paymentData) {
        processPayment(paymentData);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Log error: { statusCode: CANCELED || DEVELOPER_ERROR }
    });
    
}


function processPayment(paymentData) {
    // TODO: Send a POST request to your processor with the payload
    // https://us-central1-devrel-payments.cloudfunctions.net/google-pay-server 
    // Sorry, this is out-of-scope for this codelab.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
        const paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
        console.log('mock send token ' + paymentToken + ' to payment processor');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('mock response from processor');
            alert('done');
            console.log(paymentData);
            resolve({});
        }, 800);
    });
}
</script>
```

I am familiar with PHP and Ruby and I don't want to use third-party payment gateways for tokenization specification want to do it with the DIRECT method. I don't know what to do next and how to compare the token after payment success and don't have any idea about tokenization specification with the DIRECT method help me.
thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a web integration, consider using the [Google Pay components](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/simpler-google-pay-integration-for-react-web-developers.html). There's a [React version](https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/tree/main/src/button-react) if using React, and a [Web Component](https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/tree/main/src/button-element) version for most of the other frameworks.

As for DIRECT integration, it is strongly discouraged due to additional compliance obligations. From https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#direct:

> **Key Point:** The Direct integration allows merchants to decrypt the Google Pay response on their servers. To qualify, you must be Payments Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS) Level 1 compliant. Your servers also need to have the required infrastructure to securely handle users' payment credentials.
>
> Third parties that supply gateway or processing services on behalf of actual merchants aren't eligible to use the Direct integration. For questions about your integration as a payment service provider, [contact us](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayapigatewaypaymentprocessorinterestform/).
>
> If you don't meet the necessary prerequisites, we recommend that you use a [supported gateway](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors) to receive a payment token.

Out of interest, why don't you want to use a payment gateway?

If you still feel like you need DIRECT integration, resources on how to decrypt the token can be found at: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography.

> I don't know what to do next and how to compare the token after payment success and don't have any idea about tokenization specification with the DIRECT method help me.

You need to [generate a public/private key pair](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#public-key-format) and register the public key with the Google Pay console. You'll also need to update the `tokenizationSpecification` to include the public key (example below)

```
"tokenizationSpecification": {
  "type": "DIRECT",
  "parameters": {
    "protocolVersion": "ECv2",
    "publicKey": "BOdoXP1aiNp.....kh3JUhiSZKHYF2Y="
  }
}
```

> how to compare the token after payment success

Google Pay won't handle the payment, you will. You'll need to decrypt the payment token and get the payment details and process the payment yourself.

DIRECT integration is a more difficult integration process, so I would strongly encourage exploring other alternatives first and only consider this if you cannot use a payment gateway.